# Equivalent java cast in C#

Tags: c#

I need help to migrate a java method:

```
(int)System.currentTimeMillis(); //result -186983989 (java) return diferent values
```

But in C# return alway the same value:

```
DateTime Jan1st1970 = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
TimeSpan span = DateTime.UtcNow - Jan1st1970;
Int32 resultado = (int)span.TotalMilliseconds; //result is always -2147483648 and i need same as java
```

It is rare becouse in debug quickwatch display the correct value, but in execution `resultado` is alway -2147483648

**I need this -186983989  result, same as java.**

Comment: Just wonder, everyday I see that there is an user named "userxxxxx" is created.  How to generate this account? I guess that it maybe the same person with different ID?

Comment: maybe it makes more sense to change your code to not depend on Integer Overflow

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to use Int64 (long). Int32 isn't large enough to hold the value.

```
Int32.MaxValue = 2,147,483,647
Int64.MaxValue = 9,223,372,036,854,775,808
```

http://forums.asp.net/post/1203789.aspx

Answer (score 2):

TotalMilliseconds is a double, not an Int32. Might be your problem

Comment: I know it is wrong, but I need to emulate that java's function, my problem is that in C# it is returning alway the same result.

I need the int value of casting that big double value.

Comment: In java system.currentimemillis doesn't return an int but a long. The cast you're doing in java is more than probably losing some information also.

Answer (score 0):

To mimic the overflow behavior you could do somthing using the unchecked keyword but I don't know enough about Java to know if this correct

```
DateTime Jan1st1970 = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
TimeSpan span = DateTime.UtcNow - Jan1st1970;

unchecked{
     int mm = Int32.MaxValue;
     mm += (int)(span.TotalMilliseconds % Int32.MaxValue);
     Console.WriteLine(mm); 
}
```

As an aside  `-2147483648  = Int32.MinValue`